# SSE Error - Using m128i_i32 to define fields of a __m128i variable

Tags: c++, sse

Upon defining a `__m128i` variable in this manner:

```
__m128i a;
a.m128i_i32[0] = 65000;
```

I get the following error:

> error: request for member ‘m128i_i32’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class
>   type ‘__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}’ a.m128i_i32[0] =
>   65000;

I have included the followinf header files:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
```

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to use an MSVC-specific feature with a different compiler (gcc ?) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work under Visual where *__m128* is defined as

```
typedef union __declspec(intrin_type) __declspec(align(16)) __m128i {
__int8              m128i_i8[16];
__int16             m128i_i16[8];
__int32             m128i_i32[4];
__int64             m128i_i64[2];
unsigned __int8     m128i_u8[16];
unsigned __int16    m128i_u16[8];
unsigned __int32    m128i_u32[4];
unsigned __int64    m128i_u64[2];
} __m128i;
```

so you can access *m128_i32*, but under g++ *__m128* is defined as

```
typedef long long __m128i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
```

and your code won't be compiled.

You can assign value by

```
int32_t* p = (int32_t*)&a;
p[0] = 65000;
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. Accessing individual fields is inefficient, isn't it? Is this the right way to go about it? I can also use _mm_setr_epi32, but this is convenient in scenarios where value is dependent on another variable.

Comment: Keep in mind that the direct access breaks [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @Blue There are no instructions to set individual fields of `_m128i`, on microsoft page is written `You should not access the __m128i fields directly.`   -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26232t5c.aspx. In this way what i wrote, this assign is done by using `mov` instruction, 32 bit data is copied from one place into another, no sse2 is taken to do this assign. In order to set all 4 ints use `_mm_set_epi32`.

Comment: So I cant use `int32_t* p = (int32_t*)&a;p[3] = 65000;` ? `a` is stored sequentially in memory right? Even though SSE is not being used, it does the job, right?

Comment: @Blue Yep, `a` has 16 bytes and is stored sequentially, when accesing `a[3]` last 4 bytes will be filled by data. To set this data no sse2 instructions is used. But `strict aliasing rule` was mentioned that it may be a problem, but  
I think this code should work, because _m128i was defined with `__attribute__ (__may_alias__)`.

Comment: @Blue and rafix: `__may_alias__` only works one way: it's legal to cast the address of an `int32_t` to `(__m128i*)`, but *not* vice versa.  For type-punning the other way, you need to use a union or memcpy.  Or for this problem with SSE4.1, use `_mm_insert_epi32(vec, scalar, position)` (where position must be a compile-time constant).  To get the compiler to generate shuffles for you without SSE4.1 intrinsics, use a `union { __m128i v; int32_t i32[4]; };`  Or define your own vector type based on `int32_t` instead of `long long` wtih `__vector_size__ (16)` and use `v[2] = 65000`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh it only goes one way? I actually didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mysticial: IIRC, that's what Marc Glisse (or maybe another gcc dev) told me in an SO comment some other time this came up, when I was wondering if it was safe to use `int*` on the elements of a vector.

Answer (score 6):

`m128i_i32` is MSVC specific. And you are compiling with GCC or Clang (judging by your error message). Use `_mm_setr_epi32` instead.

```
__m128i a = _mm_setr_epi32(0, 1, 2, 3);
```