# Fastest way to initialize a __m128i constant with intrinsics?

Tags: c, visual-c++, sse, intrinsics, micro-optimization

Currently, I've got a __m128i variable, let's call it `X`. I want to xor it with a constant 128bit value and save the value back to to `X`. So, essentially `X ^= C` for some constant `C`.

Currently, I'm doing something along the lines of:

`X = _mm_xor_si128(X, _mm_set_epi64x(C_a, C_b))`

Which builds a `__m128i` from the two 64-bit parts of `C` for the xor.

My question is, this does doesn't seem like the most efficient way to initialize the __m128i constant for the xor. Would it be better to try to do some load from an aligned array? Or some other method?

I'm currently working with MSVC in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is purely about the case of constant `C`.  If you have non-constant inputs, it matters where they're coming from (memory, registers, a recent computation that you could maybe do in vector registers in the first place?) and potentially what you're doing to do with the resulting vector.  Shuffling separate scalar variables into / out of SIMD vectors kinda sucks, with a tradeoff between ALU port bottlenecks vs. latency and throughput of store/reload (and the store forwarding stall for scalar -> vector).  Store/reload is good in asm for getting lots of small elements *out* of a SIMD vector when you do want them all, though.

---

**For constant `C_a` and `C_b`, even MSVC does a good job at constant-propagation through that `_mm_set`**.  So there's no advantage to writing an implementation-specific initializer like [SSE Error - Using m128i_i32 to define fields of a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882091/sse-error-using-m128i-i32-to-define-fields-of-a-m128i-variable)

**Remember that the real determiner of performance is the assembly you can coax the compiler into producing, not really which intrinsics you use to do that.**

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128i xor_const(__m128i v) {
    return _mm_xor_si128(v, _mm_set_epi64x(0x789abc, 0x123456));
}
```

Compiled (**[on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsQAJlKtmtUAH0pyUgGdM7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrSGl16ADJ5amAHIGARpmIgArKQAOqWYRW1tew8YeXsp0Fla2%2Bg5OrvKKIbQMBMzEBH4GRpxyCphKPonJBGE29o5cckkpaQGZshWFlsWRpZwAlHKousTIHADkAKSCAMyWyHpYANR9g5p4%2BvqWBMSWAHQIU9h9AAwAglvbUvqcggAceOMAHiQSaLS1EAdHp%2BMAbi2TAOwAQnvjv%2BPEmAInVo4wkcwkl2IEi8jwgz1IoPB8gIEkwbjwADZuOcIJtzu9jgBOZh2GTjPFHQbcZwYlotKbfHZ9d4AER6bVYIB6zh6pCMPU2vNQXM041kHS6mEmQ0EvIIXMFdNIAGsXJsRFzuLz%2BYLSMKerzZCB1fKBezSHBYDBEChUPp0ewyBQIGh7XhHShRpxCRIsaQqO6CI4jRA7AreXZLMkAJ5czi8136dQEADytFYsbNpCw%2BjEwHY4ezeABuWemCNWcw5xyuiDcd5CwUhdYeDsxBj2iw9dIi1m9baNHoTDYHB4/DKonEICk1xEraNkDaqDc8QrAFoU4JxmuAOLPQ3ZXKqCCmKoZQkmDRFCJREAXoLeOhnrj3zyP2jXkpOC%2BxHLxfKVDo6RlL%2BR4JHUn5NE4NR1M%2BMEFJBt6tO0nTdEIHJcjyfKFvq5xYuM%2BiyM8yAvN6yycJs4wQAA6gAktY2BvBAuCECQ0qDMI4zaG6jrsa0XFyuGSoIJgzBYE4EBtKqzjqpyPRaqQ%2BhqthWb6oaxo9kJFrWhASCug6jjkJQ%2BnuqUyDAISwgBqwQbECGYZZpGtAxt2ibJmmGaFjmeYFlm%2BAlsoZYVrqVY1nWPTxuQ9BNlmLZth2GC9JFvZKRF5qDowLAFmOAjCJOkjSHOdgLpJeorj466bgecQ%2BGoGjPoIvCmIhpQYu4b7xA1vAPvELVOG1oH/rBQHVFkNV0AB9ThF%2BIHDf4GTlAhDQ3s0bTiqhHCCBh3LajhXLnMcGJrvhwDICRhLLFuzH4EQxDsZx3EGXdAwcW8miCWawmieJlDbQpSkySpupqXIGmmoqUnKXJgy7apXIfRDGo9LKQNCvDmmfW0ZZ2bV3BAA)**) with x64 MSVC -O2 Gv (to use vectorcall so we can see what it does when a vector is already in a register, like when this inlines), we get this fairly stupid asm which hopefully wouldn't be this bad in a larger function after inlining:

```
;; MSVC 19.10
;; this is in the .rdata section; godbolt just filters directives that aren't interesting
;; "everyone knows" that compilers put data in the right sections
__xmm@0000000000789abc0000000000123456 DB 'V4', 012H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H
        DB      0bcH, 09aH, 'x', 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H

xor_const@@16 PROC                                  ; COMDAT
        movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR __xmm@0000000000789abc0000000000123456
        pxor    xmm1, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
        ret     0
xor_const@@16 ENDP
```

We can see that the `_mm_set` intrinsic compiled to a 16-byte constant in static storage, like we want.  Failure to use `pxor xmm0, xmm1` is surprising, but [MSVC is well known for asm that's often not quite as good](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=1015) compared to GCC and/or clang.  Again, as part of a large function when it has a choice of registers, we'd probably have no extra `movdqa`.  And if the xor was in a loop, loading once outside a loop is what we want anyway.  This wasn't the most recent MSVC version; Godbolt only has the most up-to-date MSVC versions installed for C++, not C, but you tagged this C.

---

By comparison, GCC9.2 -O3 compiles to the expected memory-source PXOR that's efficient on all CPUs.

```
xor_const:
        pxor    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret

.section .rodata    # Godbolt strips out stuff like section directive; re-added manually
.LC0:
        .quad   1193046
        .quad   7903932
```

---

You could probably get a compiler to emit the same asm with a static `alignas(16)` array holding the constant, and `_mm_load_si128()` from that.  But why bother?

**One thing to *avoid* is writing `static const __m128i C = _mm_set...`** - compilers are super dumb with this and will not fold the `_mm_set` into a static constant initializer for the `__m128i`.  C compilers will refuse to compile a non-constant static initializer.  C++ compilers will reserve some BSS space and run a constructor-like function to copy from a read-only constant into that BSS space, because `_mm_set` doesn't fully optimize away in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this -- lots of great information here, I'm still going through it all in more detail now. Looks like, with the current implementation, I'm getting a `movdqa` from a constant in the code segment (`cs:xmmword...`). I'm going to try your suggestion of using an aligned array to get it to just do the pxor. But you also say I shouldn't bother -- why shouldn't I? Seems like the more performant solution.

Comment: @user2059300: Are you actually assembling that snippet of asm I copy/pasted from the Godbolt compiler explorer?  It has directives like `section .rdata` filtered out so you can just see the essential parts.  If you want to actually assemble it, use the link to the full source + asm on Godbolt and unfilter with the dropdowns.  **But really you want the compiler to inline this C function.**  The point of this is to *see* what the compiler will do in general, not to make an asm function that it has to actually `call`!!  That would be horrible.

Comment: @user2059300:  *But you also say I shouldn't bother -- why shouldn't I?* Because like I explained in the answer, the compiler will (or should) generate the same asm if you write the source that way.  I think you missed the entire point of my answer.  Since the `_mm_set` way is easier to read, use that instead.  Different ways of writing the source may sometimes get compilers to avoid missed optimizations, but you can't know which will be better on a case-by-case basis when inlining into your real code.